# Can we have both Xcode 3.2.5 and Xcode 4 on the same mac

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4

I am currently using Xcode 3.2.5 for developing my project. But, i was very impressed with Xcode 4 and want to try it out.

1. Can i have both the versions on my mac and try them out..???
2. if i install Xcode 4 and remove my previous version, will it effect my current project???

Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, but if I'm not mistaken will only work if you download Xcode 4 from the iOS Developer Center. When installing Xcode 4, make sure you install it in a separate directory from the default otherwise it will overwrite 3.2.5.

If you install Xcode 4 from the Mac App Store, you won't have the choice and all prior versions of Xcode will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

yes... install the xcode 4 in a separate directory ...